# Eclipse SVN error "svn:E210003:connection refused by the server"

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse Juno Service Release 2, and I am trying to connect to a SVN server via SVN Repository Exploring perspective but I get an "svn:E210003:connection refused by the server" error.
I tried the suggested solutions to modify Active Provider to "Manual" and "Native" also  in Network Connections  from Window->Preferences but I still face this issue. Please take note that I am not able to access command prompt due to insufficient privileges and also the credentials work for one of my colleague, so I just think it might be a proxy issue.

Could you please suggest how can I solve this issue or what to investigate further more?

Comment: You likely have to be given permission to connect to the svn server by whoever is acting as its administrator.

Comment: Thank you @BillHileman! The administrator did not provide me access to the svn server so that is why i was facing this error/issue. After my access was granted it is working.

Comment: I'll post my response as an answer so that you can mark this question as answered.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have to be given permission to connect to the svn server by whoever is acting as its administrator.